# ansible and ansible-playbook do not reply same value for kernel Fact

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I am running a vagrant VM to test ansible playbooks.

One of those playbooks includes some test based on the kernel version.
The vagrant VM is a Ubuntu 12.04. Here is the Vagrantfile.

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/precise64"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpuexecutioncap", "90", "--memory", "2048"]
  end

  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "vagrant/bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.2.2"
  config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = "vagrant/setup.yml"
  end
end
```

Now in the VM, I updated the kernel to reflect my production environment from 3.8 to 3.11, using while logged on to the VM:

```
sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-lts-saucy xserver-xorg-lts-saucy libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-saucy
```

Now, when I collect the facts of the Vagrant VM using the **ansible** command, I get:

> "ansible_kernel": "3.11.0-26-generic",

However, using the little playbook (and therefore using the **ansible-playbook** command)

```
- hosts: default
  sudo: True
  tasks:
  - debug: msg={{ ansible_kernel }}
```

I get:

> ```
> TASK: [debug msg={{ ansible_kernel }}] 
> **************************************** 
> ok: [default] => { 
>      "msg": "3.2.0-90-virtual"
> }
> ```

I am confused, why don't I see the same value for the kernel versions here?

Comment: It looks like you ran the ansible-playbook as provision script. As there was no reboot since the kernel update, the facts give you the currently used kernel and not the updated one. I think, that you ran the ansible commad after the reboot of the vm. In that case the vm uses the new kernel and the facts tell you the new version.

Comment: No sorry, I did not write it but I did restart the machine after the update. I can run both the playbook and the command and still get the difference after many reboots

Comment: But actually, it might have to do with fact caching. I'll look a bit into it

Comment: Found it. @SebastianStigler that was almost what you said actually, I cached the wrong value before reboot, but never updated the cached value. Clearing the cache did the trick! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in facts depending on the user that performs the task:
I guess you used

```
ansible -m setup machine_name
```

to get the ansible kernel.
Try also:

```
ansible -s -m setup machine_name
```

and you will see the difference